# ¿Cómo crear lotes (batches) en un dataset con elementos de distintas longitudes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, tensorflow, inteligencia-artificial

Estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de crear un dataset con `tf.data.Dataset` en TensorFlow2.x. La situación es que estoy trabajando con palabras grabadas, audios que por supuesto tienen diferentes longitudes y lo que no he logrado hacer es un dataset que devuelva una tupla `(locutor: Str, palabra: Str, mfccs: Array)` y se pueda procesar por lotes, o sea, he logrado crear un dataset con la estructura anterior el dilema se da cuando itero sobre el luego de haberle aplicado el método `dataset.batch(32)` lanzándome el error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 1. First 
element had shape [17,40] and element 1 had shape [40,40]. [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

En el error se refiere a matrices de `[17,40]` y `[40,40]` porque les extraje a los audios los coeficientes mfcc y la primera dimensión es la cantidad de tramos en los que el audio se dividió.

En fin que **mi duda se resume en como crear un dataset con items de longitud variable y que se pueda procesar por lotes(batch).**

Answer (score 1):

Para poder procesar datasets con items de longitud variable, necesitas usar el método `padded_batch`, **esto no te hará que todos tengan una longitud variable, si no que cada `batch` sea de distinta longitud**.

Es decir, si tenemos 128 datos y los dividimos en 4 batches de 32. Estos batches podrían tener la siguiente forma:

```
batch1.shape = (32, 54, 54)
batch2.shape = (32, 54, 67)
batch3.shape = (32, 54, 78)
batch4.shape = (32, 54, 86)
```

Lo que quiere decir que cada uno de los batches tiene distinta longitud, **pero los datos dentro de cada batch, tienen la misma longitud**. Para esto lo que se hace es **ordenar previamente los datos por longitud** y después crear batches segun la media de longitud de cada batch.

El método `.padded_batch()` tiene tres argumentos:

1. `batch_size`: el tamaño del batch size
2. `padded_shapes`: el tamaño de padding que se quiere poner
3. `padding_values`: el número que se quiere usar para hacer padding, si se deja en `None` este argumento, será cero, que es el número usado normalmente.
4. `drop_remainder`: este es un argumento que aparece en todas las operaciones de padding, y sirve para olvidarse de los datos restantes. Por ejemplo si tenemos 140 datos y hacemos `batch_size=32` tendremos 4 batches de 32 (que harán un total de 128 datos) y un último de 12 (para llegar a los 140), si ponemos este argumento como `True` no computará el restante (esos últimos 12 datos).

Puedes ver más sobre [`padded_batch` y los `datasets` de Tensorflow en su documentación oficial](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch)

## Bonus

El `padding` es una solución en el mundo de la ciencia de datos cuando existen datos de longitud variable, lo que se hace es recortar/ampliar nuestro conjunto de datos.

- Ampliar: si tenemos datos con poca longitud añadimos ceros (suele ser cero, aunque no tiene porque) hasta alcanzar la longitud requerida
- Reducir: recortamos datos hasta tener la longitud requerida.

Por ejemplo si tenemos 200 vectores con longitudes de 50 a 500, podemos crear un padding de 300. Lo que hará que todos los vectores después de esta operación tengan longitud 300, los que seán más largos serán recortados cuando llegen a 300 (perdiendo información), los que sean más cortos se agregarán ceros hasta llegar a 300.

Puedes ver más sobre [padding en la documentación oficial de tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/pad)